# Make Twig fallback to a 404 page when template not found

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Twig as a standalone template engine for my site. I am using a simple router called Macaw that takes a "pretty URL" and tells Twig to render the appropriate page like so:

```
Macaw::get('/(:any)', function($slug) {
    echo $GLOBALS['twig']->render('@pages/'.$slug.'.html');
});
```

It all works fine except if I try to load a non-existent page I get a horrible error like

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'Unable to find template "@pages/this-link-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad.html"

I would think that this is a very simple thing to do, but I can't figure it out logically and I can't find anything in the Twig documentation for how to handle this. I would kind of expect `twig->render()` to have a parameter for a fallback page or to except an array of pages, but apparently not.

Comment: This seems more like the responsibility of the router/framework, rather than the templating engine.  I know Slim has the `notFound` binding - perhaps Macaw has something similar?

Comment: Macaw has `Macaw::error`, but it never gets to that because it is Twig that is having the error, not Macaw. I suppose if Twig returned a 404 error rather than an error page that might do it...

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand.  The problem is that Twig is throwing an exception, and this halts the script.  Does Macaw have an exception-handling route?  In Slim they have an [`error`](http://docs.slimframework.com/errors/500/) route that can catch an exception and then render an error page (or in your case, a 404 page).  Sorry to plug Slim again, but it's what I know.

Comment: You might want to consider switching to Slim anyway, if possible.  I just looked at Macaw's repository and it doesn't look like there has been any work on it in over 5 months.

Comment: Are you saying Slim has a way of catching the Twig error?

Comment: Slim has a way of catching *any* exception.  You can make it specific to that Twig exception you're getting, or you can have it handle any generic php `Exception`.

Comment: Nice, well I probably should switch to Slim, and it hopefully won't be too much trouble. When I started the site I just picked Macaw because it looked simple and did just what I want. I thought Slim was too much, but maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was simply to use a try/catch block when rendering the page. I switched to Slim for routing, but it didn't make any difference over Macaw. So now I have something like this:

```
try {
    $app->render("pages/$slug.html", $data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $app->render('pages/404.html', array('error'=> $e));
}
```